# Is it possible to override the type descriptor for an existing .net type?

Tags: .net, reflection, typeconverter

Or more specifically

1) Can I assign a type descriptor to a property

2) If so, what's the best way of getting the type converter at runtime.

Basically I have configuration objects that are populated using reflection. So far this works just for simple types (string, int, datetime) but I wanted to support converting comma separated lists to List.

So far I've achieved this by deriving a custom type "`ConvertableList<T>`" from `List<T>` and decorating that with my custom type converter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can associate `TypeConverter` s to existing types like:

```
    TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(List<int>),
        new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(MyTypeConverter)));
```

(somewhere during startup)

Then to *get* the converter, the standard code should work:

```
    TypeConverter conv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(List<int>));
```

or:

```
    object obj = new List<int>();
    ...
    TypeConverter conv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(obj);
```

Comment: would my descriptor always have priority over the default?

Comment: @Ben - for any code that uses `TypeDescriptor`, yes. It is possible that some code might decide to check for `IList` (non-generic) and special-case it somehow, though. I can't change their special-case code.

Comment: They are largely cumulative, so that isn't simple. Try to avoid the need to do that... I *suspect* (untested) you could do it by storing the *provider* (`TypeDescriptor.GetProvider`) and pushing back the old value (`TypeDescriptor.AddProvider`).