# Entity Framework: Map a Guid property in C# to a Database String

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, converters

My EF code first application has to work with SQL Server and Oracle.

- In Oracle, there is no Guid type, so they are stored as `nvarchar2(38)`.
- In SQL Server, there is a GUID type and so there is no problem.

Is there a way to globally override the behavior of the Oracle Entity Framework provider such that any columns in the database that map to Guid types in my POCO classes can have custom conversion behavior?

Now some might say, "Don't store Guids as strings in Oracle! Use RAW(16) instead because EF plays nicely with that". Unfortunately, that is not an option here.

Can I "teach" Entity framework how to convert string database values to Guids?

**Update**

I just found [this](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2639292-simple-type-mapping-or-mapped-type-conversion-supp) link, which suggests that the capability isn't native to EF6, but may be out in future releases.

Also, I prefer not to have custom converters by mapping private properties as shown [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/451445)

**Update**

Here's the stack trace from of the "Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Guid'" exception

`at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToType(Type type, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.ChangeType(Object sourceValue, Type targetType)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader1.GetUntypedValueDefault(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetColumnValueWithErrorHandling[TColumn](Int32 ordinal)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)`

I found a post that Asad contributed to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018307/how-to-override-net-type-converters/19022931#19022931) that suggests you can change the behavior of System.Convert.ChangeType() which is getting called by the Oracle Data Access Provider

Comment: Yes, you can teach EF to do several things when translating your LINQ expression into SQL. You'll need to write an interceptor to do this.

Comment: Why is sql-server listed as a tag?  The content of the question does not have any thing to do with sql-server.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Someone must have edited it. I did not list it as a tag. I just removed it.

Comment: @Asad Do you have any good places to start looking at creating an interceptor? Although... I'm not trying modify the LINQ to SQL... I just want to grab the datatype that comes back from the Ado Provider and tell it how to convert it to a guid. Currently it tries to do a straight cast, which doesn't work.

Comment: @matrixugly Sure. See [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework6/database-command-interception.aspx). Another approach you could take is to have *two* model classes. The SQLSrv ones have a Guid `Id` property and the Oracle ones have a string `Id`. Have a mapping and DBSet for each class in its respective context. Now add an interface that has all the important properties in your model and a `Guid` `Id` prop. Finally, before you use either model from either context, cast to this interface.

Comment: Here's a sample of what the interface and models will look like: http://ideone.com/5Ih8Xp. Whenever you do a query of `OracleFoo`s for example, you can do `oracleFoos.Where(...).Cast<IFoo>()`.

Comment: @Asad I just ran into a post (answered by you) http://stackoverflow.com/a/19022931/2437521 It suggests I can tell the CLR how to convert a string to a guid. EF calls the System.Convert.ChangeType() method, so maybe this is where I could start

Answer (score 0):

I never did find a solution. Unless a different version of the Oracle EF provider comes out to support this, the solution is to map the string property of the thing that represents your guid to a string in the db. I did it like this

`class Thing
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(38)] //38 is the length of a guid with curlies on it
    public string GuidID { get; set;}
}`

Then I just make sure to do the same ToString() format for guids when storing new values, and Guid.Parse() for retrieving the values as Chris1804505 mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score -1):

C# has a built in GUID Class you may want to think about using that.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Then when you need to insert the class in to the database you can GUID.ToString() and also create a guid via Guid.Parse(GUID).
I may take a little finessing but it should work for you.

As far as EF is concerned. It's been a while since I have worked with it but you will probably want to change the Generated to code to work. Or implement a custom class or property to update/change the GUID

Comment: I am using a guid. Trying to figure out how EF converts the db string to the c# guid. Looking for a specific example of how this config works.