# Can't override Dictionary keys serialization/deserialization with Json.net

Tags: .net, json.net

I have a simple type containing a property that is `IDictionary<decimal, int>`:

```
    public class CountEvent
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_ts")]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public String Pair { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "dir")]
    public String Direction { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<Decimal, Int32> Data { get; set; }

    public RateCountEvent()
    {
        Data = new Dictionary<Decimal, Int32>();
    }
}
```

I used IDictionary on purpose, since I provide either Dictionary or SortedDictionary instance at runtime. Changing property type to Dictionary class doesn't affect the behaviour. 
I would like to provide custom serialization logic for Decimal (namely, remove trailing zeroes), and I've written a class for that:

```
    public class DecimalWithoutTrailingZerosConverter: JsonConverter
{
    private readonly IFormatProvider formatProvider;

    public DecimalWithoutTrailingZerosConverter(IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        this.formatProvider = formatProvider;
    }

    public override Boolean CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Decimal);
    }

    public override Object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.String)
            throw new Exception("Wrong Token Type");

        return Convert.ToDecimal(reader.Value, formatProvider);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        String val;

        if (value is decimal)
        {
            val = ((Decimal) value).ToString("G29", formatProvider);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Expected date object value.");
        }
        writer.WriteValue(val);
    }
}
```

Yep, I know JSON serialization is typically culture-invariant. Not my point here. 
The thing is, when I add my converter to serializer settings, **it is considered** (`CanConvert` method is hit by debugger), **but Decimal type never shows in there as `objectType` parameter**, while all the other types do (my type CountEvent, DateTime, String, Dictionary (I think it consideres run-time type) and Int32). 
I've looked at the library code and it seems there's a custom logic in `KeyValuePairConverter` class that serializes dictionaries (I assume). 
 The question is - is behaviour I'm seeing right? Can it be overriden? 
P.S. *I'm not saying the library is wrong* (after all, thousands of people use it every day), I'm just trying to find a way to make it work for this scenario.

Comment: The `ctor` for your class `CountEvent` is incorrect.

Comment: also you're never sending `decimal` , a dictionary instead.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh how so? ctor should be empty?

Comment: about never sending a decimal - I understand that, but Int32 type is considered by `CanConvert` method. shouldn't `Decimal` be too?

Comment: apparantly the `Int32` isn't related to the `Dictionary<decimal, int>`. All the property getters are getting called for their types, but not for that last `Int32` consideration.

Comment: From http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm: *When serializing a dictionary, the keys of the dictionary are converted to strings and used as the JSON object property names. The string written for a key can be customized by either overriding ToString() for the key type or by implementing a TypeConverter. A TypeConverter will also support converting a custom string back again when deserializing a dictionary.*

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh I can post the code I use for serialization, there's nothing in there but an instance of my class

Comment: @dbc thank you, I'll look into it. I knew I missed something

Comment: @dbc one more question - can you please provide an example? I've written my TypeConverter, decorated property with an attribute pointing to it, but it's not called

Comment: @dbc and when I did so with a class, the whole object is passed to `ConvertTo` method

Answer (score 1):

The reason your `DecimalWithoutTrailingZerosConverter` is not used for dictionary keys is that Json.NET does not serialize the keys - it merely converts them to strings.  From the [docs](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm):

> When serializing a dictionary, the keys of the dictionary are converted to strings and used as the JSON object property names. The string written for a key can be customized by either overriding ToString() for the key type or by implementing a TypeConverter. A TypeConverter will also support converting a custom string back again when deserializing a dictionary.

Thus, to get the output you need, you could override the system `TypeConverter` for `decimal` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018307/how-to-override-net-type-converters) -- but I wouldn't really recommend it since this will change the converter used for `decimal` everywhere in your application, with various unforseeable consequences.

The alternative would be to write a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for all dictionaries implementing `IDictionary<decimal, TValue>` for some `TValue`:

```
public class DecimalDictionaryWithoutTrailingZerosConverter : DecimalWithoutTrailingZerosConverterBase
{
    public DecimalDictionaryWithoutTrailingZerosConverter(IFormatProvider formatProvider) : base(formatProvider) { }

    public override Boolean CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        var types = objectType.GetDictionaryKeyValueTypes().ToList();
        return types.Count == 1 && types[0].Key == typeof(Decimal);
    }

    object ReadJsonGeneric<TValue>(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, IDictionary<decimal, TValue> existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartObject)
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Invalid object type " + reader.TokenType);
        if (existingValue == null)
        {
            var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType);
            existingValue = (IDictionary<decimal, TValue>)contract.DefaultCreator();
        }
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.Comment:
                    break;
                case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                    {
                        var name = reader.Value.ToString();
                        var key = TokenToDecimal(JsonToken.String, name);
                        if (!reader.Read())
                            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Missing value at path: {0}", reader.Path));
                        var value = serializer.Deserialize<TValue>(reader);
                        existingValue.Add(key, value);
                    }
                    break;
                case JsonToken.EndObject:
                    return existingValue;
                default:
                    throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unknown token {0} at path: {1} ", reader.TokenType, reader.Path));
            }
        }
        throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unclosed object at path: {0}", reader.Path));
    }

    public override Object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        try
        {
            var keyValueTypes = objectType.GetDictionaryKeyValueTypes().Single(); // Throws an exception if not exactly one.
            var method = GetType().GetMethod("ReadJsonGeneric", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { keyValueTypes.Value });
            return genericMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is JsonException)
                throw;
            // Wrap the TypeInvocationException in a JsonSerializerException
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Failed to deserialize " + objectType, ex);
        }
    }

    void WriteJsonGeneric<TValue>(JsonWriter writer, IDictionary<decimal, TValue> value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (var pair in value)
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName(DecimalToToken(pair.Key));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, pair.Value);
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        try
        {
            var keyValueTypes = value.GetType().GetDictionaryKeyValueTypes().Single(); // Throws an exception if not exactly one.
            var method = GetType().GetMethod("WriteJsonGeneric", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { keyValueTypes.Value });
            genericMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { writer, value, serializer });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is JsonException)
                throw;
            // Wrap the TypeInvocationException in a JsonSerializerException
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Failed to serialize " + value, ex);
        }
    }
}

public class DecimalWithoutTrailingZerosConverter : DecimalWithoutTrailingZerosConverterBase
{
    public DecimalWithoutTrailingZerosConverter(IFormatProvider formatProvider) : base(formatProvider) { }

    public override Boolean CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Decimal);
    }

    public override Object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return TokenToDecimal(reader.TokenType, reader.Value);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(DecimalToToken(value));
    }
}

public abstract class DecimalWithoutTrailingZerosConverterBase : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly IFormatProvider formatProvider;

    public DecimalWithoutTrailingZerosConverterBase(IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        this.formatProvider = formatProvider;
    }

    protected string DecimalToToken(decimal value)
    {
        return value.ToString("G29", formatProvider);
    }

    protected string DecimalToToken(object value)
    {
        if (value is decimal)
        {
            return DecimalToToken((Decimal)value);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Expected date object value.");
        }
    }

    protected decimal TokenToDecimal(JsonToken tokenType, object value)
    {
        if (tokenType != JsonToken.String)
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Wrong Token Type");
        return Convert.ToDecimal(value, formatProvider);
    }
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Return all interfaces implemented by the incoming type as well as the type itself if it is an interface.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetInterfacesAndSelf(this Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (type.IsInterface)
            return new[] { type }.Concat(type.GetInterfaces());
        else
            return type.GetInterfaces();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Type, Type>> GetDictionaryKeyValueTypes(this Type type)
    {
        foreach (Type intType in type.GetInterfacesAndSelf())
        {
            if (intType.IsGenericType
                && intType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>))
            {
                var args = intType.GetGenericArguments();
                if (args.Length == 2)
                    yield return new KeyValuePair<Type, Type>(args[0], args[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new DecimalWithoutTrailingZerosConverter(culture), new DecimalDictionaryWithoutTrailingZerosConverter(culture) },
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rateCountEvent, settings);
```

Note the use of a single converter for all types of decimal dictionary.  Note also that the converter uses the `existingValue` if one is present.  Thus if the constructor in your `RateCountEvent` allocates a sorted dictionary rather than a dictionary, the sorted dictionary will be populated.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pX2X1S).

Incidentally, you might want to extend your `DecimalWithoutTrailingZerosConverter` to handle `decimal?` as well as `decimal`.

Comment: the problem was solved in a similar way with a friend's help. thanks